# Hibernate - define formula at runtime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an application that is based on Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.2.16.Final.

There are some entities annotated with JPA annotations. Now I would like to define "formula properties". It is possible to do it in a static way by manually adding some properties annotated with "@org.hibernate.annotations.Formula" annotation, however I need to do it dynamically (at runtime). Is it possible?

Comment: check it out.add annotation on head of getter method:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441570/does-hibernate4-1-still-support-formula-annotation

Comment: I need to define formula as an sql statement (with function call) in order to be able to sort by this formula property. Getter does not match my case.

Comment: Hi  I dont know if you can have dynamically generated formula but you can use Criteria and add Restrictions dynamically in such cases..Is there any other issue with it?